# Cohomology of contractile space

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

Let $\left( X, x_0\right) $ be a pointed topological space. I don not require that $X$ is Hausdorff. Suppose $X$ is contractible, i.e. that there is a homotopy $F:X \times [0,1] \to X$ such that $F(0)= Id_X$ and $F(1) = \{x_0\}$. Let $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ be a locally constant $\mathbb{Z}$-sheaf. I think that $H^p\left(X , \widehat{ \mathbb{Z}} \right) = \{0\}$ for all $p > 0$ where $H^p$ are sheaf cohomology explained in Hartshorne's book. Is it true? If it is true, how this fact can be proven.There is a theorem in Bredon's book (page 80).
\begin{theorem} Any two properly homotopic maps (with respect to $\Phi$ and $\Psi$)
of a space $X$  into a space $Y$ induce identical homomorphisms
$H^*_\Psi(Y;G)\to  H^*_\Phi(X;G)$,
where $G$ is any constant coefficient group.

\end{theorem}
Note the special cases:
(a)  $\Phi = cld = \Psi$. In this case, "properly homotopic" is the same as
"homotopic."
(b) $X, Y$ locally compact Hausdorff, $\Phi = c = \Psi$.
Is the case (a) is relevant to my situation?

Comment: Is sheaf cohomology preserved under homotopy equivalence? Is  $H^p(\{x_0\},\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}) = \{0\}$ for all $p>0$? If the answer to both is yes, the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Thank you very much